# How to post message on facebook friends wall in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using following code for posting message on facebook friends wall through my android application.It was working before 6th feb2013.but from 7th feb 2013 it giving me an error like, got response:

`{"error":{"message":"(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}`

My code is,

```
public void postToWall(String message){
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);  
    parameters.putString("description", "topic share"); 
    try {
        facebook.request("me");
        //              String response = facebook.request("Mrunal.Junghare/feed", parameters, "POST");
        String response = facebook.request(""+frienduser_id+""+"/feed", parameters, "POST");
        //          System.out.println("name111111========"+""+ListActivity.user_name+"/feed");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Blank response.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message posted to facebook wall!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to post to wall!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

How to solve problem of feb 2013 breaking changes..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883063/how-to-post-message-on-facebook-wall-using-facebook-android-sdk-integrate-androi?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    private void postToFacebook(String review) {
    mProgress.setMessage("Posting ...");
    mProgress.show();

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("message", review);
    params.putString("name", "Message");


    mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST",
            new WallPostListener());
}

private final class WallPostListener extends BaseRequestListener {
    public void onComplete(final String response) {
        mRunOnUi.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProgress.cancel();

                Toast.makeText(Mainactivity.this, "Posted to Facebook",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here having sample code use this  [Click here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-facebook-sdk-to-post-status-from-android/)